# Novel about a comet hitting the moon

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to track down a novel (or novels) about a comet that is heading towards earth.  The hero and heroine smash an asteroid into said comet and it ends up hitting the moon instead.  The end of the novel (or second novel in the series) have the main characters attempting to get off the moon before the comet hits.

It would have been published sometime in the 80's or early 90's and was before the whole Armageddon/Deep Impact comet movies.  I think I remember reading that the author at some point had worked for NASA but I'm unsure about that.

Comment: I guess this is still open? I'm pretty sure I have that book. Need to dig it out of my book shelf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.
ThunderStrike! by Michael McCollum.
[image]

The reprint was in 2009 but the original was in 1989

Answer (score 3):

There's [MoonFall](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/337134.Moonfall) by Jack McDevitt. However that is about a comet that hits the Moon directly. Chunks of it hit the Earth, and causes one or two problems to people.

[image: Moonfall cover]

Comment: Moonfall was my first thought as well. Though it was published a bit later than the question notes. I.e. it came out in 1998, the same year as Armageddon and Deep Impact.